# Show that there is an operator $T$ in $\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\alpha_nz^n}$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R$, $0<R\leq\infty$. If $A\in\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}$ and $\| A\|<R$, show that there is an operator $T$ in $\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}$ such that for any $h,g\in\mathcal{H}$, $\langle Th,g\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\alpha_n\langle A^nh,g\rangle}$

My attemp: I know that $\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}\equiv \mathcal{B(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{H})}$ is the set of bounded linear transformations from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$, but I'm very stuck with this problem, any hint pls! Thanks

Comment: What about $T:=\sum_n \alpha_n A^n$? This series converges in $B(H)$ due to the assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Define $[h,g] \colon \mathcal{H} \times \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $[h,g] := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_n \left<A^n h, g \right>$. Then

$$ |[h,g]| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |\alpha_n| \left| \left< A^n h, g \right> \right| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |\alpha_n| ||A||^n ||h|| ||g|| = \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |\alpha_n| ||A^n|| \right) ||h|| ||g|| $$

and so $[h,g]$ is a well-defined, bounded, sesquilinear form. Then the [Riesz lemma](http://planetmath.org/rieszrepresentationtheoremofboundedsesquilinearforms) guarantess that there exists a unique bounded operator $T \colon \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ that satisfies $\left< Th, g \right> = [h,g]$ for all $h,g \in \mathcal{H}$.

Alternatively, you can define $T$ explicitly by $T = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_n A^n$, show that the sum converges in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ and that it satisfies $\left<Th, g \right> = [h,g]$.

Comment: +1 for using Riesz representation for bounded sesquilinear form.